# How do I get the default billing/shipping customer profile in code?

Tags: commerce

Is there a way to get the default billing/shipping customer profile from a user?

I'm getting all customer profiles with:

```
$profiles = commerce_customer_profile_load_multiple(array(), array('uid' => $user->uid));
```

But which customer profile was set as default by the user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get default user profile address with

```
commerce_addressbook_get_default_profile_id($uid, $type)
```

**Returns the default profile id for a specific uid and profile type.**

**@param $uid**
    The uid of the user whose default profile id should be returned.

**@param $type**
    The type of customer profile to look up.

**@return**
   The id of the default profile if set, FALSE otherwise.

An example if want get  current user `shipping` addresss use below code :

```
global $user;
$default_pid=commerce_addressbook_get_default_profile_id($user->uid,'shipping');
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that if you refer to the default field in relation with the user, you're using [Commerce Addressbook](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_addressbook), you've got an api function to get the default profile given a user id and the profile type: [commerce_addressbook_get_default_profile_id](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/commerce_addressbook/tree/commerce_addressbook.module#n485)

If you're not, you can get the profiles used by a given customer using the customer profile reference field for *billing / shipping / whatever* and consulting the variable `commerce_customer_profile_' . $type . '_field'`

So for loading the profiles of a given type you can use [Entity Field Query](https://drupal.org/node/1343708) using the customer user id against the order entity.

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$result = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'commerce_order')
  ->propertyCondition('uid', 0)
  ->execute();
if (!empty($result['commerce_order'])) {
  $orders = entity_load('commerce_order', array_keys($result['commerce_order']));
}
```

And then wrap the entity or use field_get_items:

```
$field_name = variable_get('commerce_customer_profile_billing_field', '');
$order_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);
$order_wrapper->{$field_name}->value();
```

Answer (score 0):

This might Help (Only billing i have mentioned here, you can change your condition depending on your needs).

```
$uid = "1"; //Define user id for which default address is to be found
$query = db_select("commerce_addressbook_defaults","c");
$query->fields("c",array("profile_id"));
$query->condition("uid",$uid);
$query->condition("type","billing");
$output = $query->execute()->fetchObject();

$profile_id = $output->profile_id;
if(!empty($profile_id)){
    $franchisee_info = commerce_customer_profile_load ($profile_id);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($franchisee_info);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```